# ASP.NET MVC Jquery send image to action for upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading

I everyone, Im working on a project about MVC5 about food and I want create a page for user to submit their food.

I have a class calles MyFood:

```
namespace WeLoveFOODs.Models
{
    public class MyFood
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string descriptions { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I have a form for user submit their food:

```
@model WeLoveFOODs.Models.MyFood
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Food";
}

<h2>Submit My Food</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descriptions)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.descriptions)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descriptions)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.image)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.image)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.image)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now I want a button beside the input box for image that when I click it will show a form with a `file chooser` (or something), and a button. When i choose the img and click btn, the file will be send to an UpLoad Action (using JQuery), maybe something like:

```
public string UpLoadImage(HttpPostedFileBase SelectedImg)
{
    string Path = '~/Upload/';
    string NewName = randomString() + '.jpg';
    //upload Img with new name is NewName to Path
    return NewName;
}
```

in which the img will be upload to folder `~/Upload` with the name changed to `some_random_string.jpg` and the action will return that new name, `JQuery function` will take the `some_random_string.jpg` name and put in the input box for image.

I was hoping the Jquery function would be like:

```
$("#btn_upload_img").click(function(){
    HttpPostedFileBase img = $('input[type="file"]').val();
    var url = "/Food/UpLoadImage";
    $.post(url, SelectedImg: img, function(data){
        $("#image").val(data);
    });
});
```

Could someone please give me help on this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

File upload using Ajax depends on the browser you are using. For modern browsers you can use Ajax to post images to server but for older browsers you will have to rely on plugins.

For plugins I would suggest you to use [www.uploadify.com](http://www.uploadify.com/)

For Ajax Upload, you can follow [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/) tutorial